# how to replace decimal in linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, decimal

I have a csv file with error in one field, the fields are separated by `","` but the error is in decimal field, for example `34.25,"` i need replace by `34.25","`.

Search `,"` and replace by `","` is not option, others fields will modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the character before `,"` is not a double quote, and if it's not, add the double quote:

```
sed 's/\([^"]\),"/\1","/'
```

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, You appreciate visual confirmation (in an editor) before replacing, You can do try this in Vim -

```
:%s/,"/","/gc
```

PS: Drop the 'c' at the end if you don't want vim to prompt you to confirm the substitutions.